# VBA nested Do Until Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a spreadsheet that has 17 sheets, with sheets 2-16 containing invoice data I am interested in.

As an example, if a person's name in column 4 of Sheets(2) appears in Sheets(1), then I want to sum the amount of money they have charged (which is found in column 10 of Sheets(2)). Spreadsheets 2-16 are laid out exactly the same, except they contain a different number of entries and the data is different.

There are three $ sums I am interested in computing and then displaying at the top of each sheet: two sums of money represent two different divisions, and the last is simply the total (w_sum, smb_sum, and total)

The problem I'm having is that every sheet displays the sums from Sheets(2), and not their own. However, when I remove the outer For loop and manually change the sheet number, I get the correct values. I hope I'm being clear with my question, and I would greatly appreciate any help. I just started playing around with VBA the other day, so I'm not too familiar with the syntax, but I think my logic is right or almost right.

```
Sub GetSums()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim w_sum As Currency
    Dim smb_sum As Currency
    Dim total As Currency

    w_sum = 0
    smb_sum = 0
    total = 0
    i = 15

    For j = 2 To 17

        Sheets(j).Activate

        Do Until Cells(i, 6).Value = 0

            If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("D2:D91"), 0)) Then
                w_sum = w_sum + Cells(i, 10).Value
            End If
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("E2:E91"), 0)) Then
                smb_sum = smb_sum + Cells(i, 10).Value
            End If
            total = total + Cells(i, 10).Value
            i = i + 1

        Loop

        Cells(10, 4).Value = w_sum
        Cells(11, 4).Value = smb_sum
        Cells(12, 4).Value = total

    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable as worksheet:

`Dim ws As Worksheet`

Then instead of calling `Sheets(j).Activate`, you can bind `ws` to sheet number `j`:

`Set ws = Sheets(j)`

Then you can use `ws.cell(i, 4).value` instead of just `cells(i, 4).value` which tends to behave arbitrarily.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually just realized that the i counter needs to be inside the For loop and before the Do Until

Comment: Yeah thats right... the counter didn't reset... i missed that too :)